# iReport 5.0.0: Remove space betwen Y bar and plot for Timeseries chart

Tags: java, charts, jasper-reports, timeserieschart

I'm trying to create a *Timeseries chart* in *iReport 5.0.0* and want to remove the space between the Y axis and the lines in the graph, how would i do that?

I already have a Customizer class and have tried to thinker whit some of the values in it but to no luck. Any help much appreciated.

Added a datescale to the y axis and it seems like my first date is at 2011-06-30 but my x-axis starts att 2011-05-01 for som reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your chart customizer, cast your plot to an `XYPlot` (or just call `chart.getXYPlot()`) and then call `setAxisOffset` on it. This method sets the gap between the axes and the plot. 
[(javadoc here)](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/XYPlot.html#setAxisOffset%28org.jfree.ui.RectangleInsets%29)

Removing the gap from the y-axis should be as simple as calling:

```
plot.setAxisOffset(new RectangleInsets(5.0, 0.0, 5.0, 5.0));
```

Removing all of the gaps can be done with:

```
plot.setAxisOffset(new RectangleInsets(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
```

or

```
plot.setAxisOffset(RectangleInsets.ZERO_INSETS);
```

**Edit:**
By default, the plot will begin slightly before the first data point. If you want the data to begin immediately at the edge of the plot, call `setMinimumDate` on your date axis, setting it to the same value as the first point in your dataset.

Comment: Hi Jon and thanks for the answer. It looks a little better now but there is still a gap betwen the y axis and the line. Could it have something to to with the x axis? It seems like it shows dates for every 4th month so meaby it somehow pushes the shale wrong? For example Jul-2011, Oct-2011 and so on.

Comment: @user2556565, I have put in a quick edit to address your issue.

Comment: Thanks a million, that seemed to make the graph look alright. I added on last question above. After that I think I'm more than satisfied and will mark this question as resolved.

Comment: Think I will just open up a separate question for that question. Think this case is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The axis now works. I did this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,2011);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,05);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,30);

java.util.Date d = cal.getTime();
domainAxis.setMinimumDate(d);
```

The above answer is resolved. I will also open up a new thread on how to get the first value in a series. But that will be a separate question.